# How to implement a WrapPanel with a header and footer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, panel

I am trying to implement a custom control that acts similarly to a standard WrapPanel, but that allows you to specify a header and footer. Visually, this is what I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

I have created a custom control that seems to leave room for the header and footer items, but I am unable to get them to visually appear. This is my first attempt at any sort of custom control, so any help or input is appreciated!

C#

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MyProject.Extras
{
    public class HeaderedFooteredPanel : Panel
    {
        public FrameworkElement Header
        {
            get { return (FrameworkElement) GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
        }
        public FrameworkElement Footer
        {
            get { return (FrameworkElement)GetValue(FooterProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FooterProperty, value); }
        }

        public static DependencyProperty HeaderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Header),
            typeof(FrameworkElement),
            typeof(HeaderedFooteredPanel),
            new PropertyMetadata((object)null));
        public static DependencyProperty FooterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(Footer),
            typeof(FrameworkElement),
            typeof(HeaderedFooteredPanel),
            new PropertyMetadata((object)null));

        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
        {
            double x = 0.0;
            double y = 0.0;
            double largestY = 0.0;
            double largestX = 0.0;

            var measure = new Action<FrameworkElement>(element =>
            {
                element.Measure(constraint);
                if (x > 0 &&                                                // Not the first item on this row
                    (x + element.DesiredSize.Width > constraint.Width) &&   // We are too wide to fit on this row
                    ((largestY + element.DesiredSize.Height) <= MaxHeight)) // We have enough room for this on the next row
                {
                    y = largestY;
                    x = element.DesiredSize.Width;
                }
                else
                {
                    /* 1) Always place the first item on a row even if width doesn't allow it
                     *      otherwise:
                     * 2) Keep placing on this row until we reach our width constraint
                     *      otherwise:
                     * 3) Keep placing on this row if the max height is reached */

                    x += element.DesiredSize.Width;
                }

                largestY = Math.Max(largestY, y + element.DesiredSize.Height);
                largestX = Math.Max(largestX, x);
            });

            measure(Header);

            foreach (FrameworkElement child in InternalChildren)
            {
                measure(child);
            }

            measure(Footer);

            return new Size(largestX, largestY);
        }

        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            double x = 0.0;
            double y = 0.0;
            double largestY = 0.0;
            double largestX = 0.0;

            var arrange = new Action<FrameworkElement>(element =>
            {
                if (x > 0 &&                                                // Not the first item on this row
                    (x + element.DesiredSize.Width > finalSize.Width) &&    // We are too wide to fit on this row
                    ((largestY + element.DesiredSize.Height) <= MaxHeight)) // We have enough room for this on the next row
                {
                    y = largestY;
                    element.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0.0, y), element.DesiredSize));
                    x = element.DesiredSize.Width;
                }
                else
                {
                    /* 1) Always place the first item on a row even if width doesn't allow it
                     *      otherwise:
                     * 2) Keep placing on this row until we reach our width constraint
                     *      otherwise:
                     * 3) Keep placing on this row if the max height is reached */

                    element.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(x, y), element.DesiredSize));
                    x += element.DesiredSize.Width;
                }

                largestY = Math.Max(largestY, y + element.DesiredSize.Height);
                largestX = Math.Max(largestX, x);
            });

            arrange(Header);

            foreach (FrameworkElement child in InternalChildren)
            {
                arrange(child);
            }

            arrange(Footer);

            return new Size(largestX, largestY);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage in XAML:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeItems}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SomeTemplate}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <extras:HeaderedFooteredPanel>
                <extras:HeaderedFooteredPanel.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="Header" />
                </extras:HeaderedFooteredPanel.Header>
                <extras:HeaderedFooteredPanel.Footer>
                    <TextBlock Text="Footer" />
                </extras:HeaderedFooteredPanel.Footer>
            </extras:HeaderedFooteredPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your code to override the `OnRender()` method to actually _draw_ the header and footer items. Please explain what it is, in the code you posted above, that you expected to cause that to happen?

Comment: I suspect the issue is due the fact that while, yes you are making room for the items using the Measure and Arrange overrides, the list is still data-bound to {Binding SomeItems}. Therefore when WPF goes in to lay down the items, it's still only dealing with the items in the bound list.

I may be wrong, but here's another way you might consider if your initial approach does not work.

What if you wrapped your list with an expandable element that included the Header and Footer? In other words, don't make the header and footer part of the list, but do make it part of your control.

Comment: @PeterDuniho The DrawingContext supplied to the OnRender() method only seems to support very basic rendering commands. Surely you don't have to re-write the rendering code for a standard WPF control, but I am not seeing a way to draw them on my own. As I said in my original post, this is the first time I have attempted to create a custom control, and I haven't been very successful in finding useful documentation or examples on how to create a custom control like this.

Comment: @ryancdotnet I agree that the problem is probably WPF not knowing that it needs to lay down the header and footer controls, (perhaps somehow in the OnRender() method as PeterDuniho suggested?). I'm not sure what you mean by not making the header and footer part of the list but still making it part of the control. That was my original intent!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write in the comments:

> The DrawingContext supplied to the OnRender() method only seems to support very basic rendering commands. Surely you don't have to re-write the rendering code for a standard WPF control, but I am not seeing a way to draw them on my own

If by "basic" you mean you are restricted to only `DrawingContext` operations, then yes. That's exactly what it's for. That's actually the drawing API for WPF. At a higher level, you are dealing with visuals and framework elements, which hide the actual drawing activity. But to override the way such objects are drawn, will require diving down into that level of drawing, replacing it or supplementing it as necessary.

One significant difficulty that would probably arise (besides the more fundamental difficulty of dealing with drawing at that level) is that at that level, there is no such thing as data templates, and no way to access the rendering behaviors of other elements. You have to draw *everything* from scratch. This would wind up negating a big part of what makes WPF so useful: convenient and powerful control over the exact on-screen representation of data through the use of built-in controls and the properties that give you control over their appearance.

I have only rarely found that a custom `Control` sub-class is really needed. The only time this comes up is when you need to have complete control over the entire rendering process, to draw something that is simply not possible any other way, or to provide the required performance (at the expense of convenience). *Much* more often, nearly all of the time even, what you want to do is leverage the existing controls and get them to do all the heavy lifting for you.

In this particular case, I think the key to solving your problem is a type called `CompositeCollection`. Just like it sounds, it allows you build up a collection as a composite of other objects, including other collections. With this, you can combine your header and footer data into a single collection that can be displayed by an `ItemsControl`.

In some cases, just creating that collection and using it directly with an `ItemsControl` object might be sufficient for your needs. But if you want a whole, reusable user-defined control that understands the idea of a header and footer, you can wrap the `ItemsControl` in a `UserControl` object that exposes the properties you need, including a `Header` and `Footer` property. Here is an example of what that might look like:

**XAML:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestSO43008469HeaderFooterWrapPanel.HeaderFooterWrapPanel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestSO43008469HeaderFooterWrapPanel"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <ItemsControl x:Name="wrapPanel1">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  </ItemsControl>
</UserControl>
```

**C#:**

```
public partial class HeaderFooterWrapPanel : UserControl
{
    private const int _kheaderIndex = 0;
    private const int _kfooterIndex = 2;

    private readonly CompositeCollection _composedCollection = new CompositeCollection();
    private readonly CollectionContainer _container = new CollectionContainer();

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Header", typeof(string), typeof(HeaderFooterWrapPanel),
        new PropertyMetadata((o, e) => _OnHeaderFooterPropertyChanged(o, e, _kheaderIndex)));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FooterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Footer", typeof(string), typeof(HeaderFooterWrapPanel),
         new PropertyMetadata((o, e) => _OnHeaderFooterPropertyChanged(o, e, _kfooterIndex)));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(HeaderFooterWrapPanel),
        new PropertyMetadata(_OnItemsSourceChanged));

    private static void _OnHeaderFooterPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e, int index)
    {
        HeaderFooterWrapPanel panel = (HeaderFooterWrapPanel)d;

        panel._composedCollection[index] = e.NewValue;
    }

    private static void _OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        HeaderFooterWrapPanel panel = (HeaderFooterWrapPanel)d;

        panel._container.Collection = panel.ItemsSource;
    }

    public string Header
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
    }

    public string Footer
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FooterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FooterProperty, value); }
    }

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public HeaderFooterWrapPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _container.Collection = ItemsSource;
        _composedCollection.Add(Header);
        _composedCollection.Add(_container);
        _composedCollection.Add(Footer);
        wrapPanel1.ItemsSource = _composedCollection;
    }
}
```

Noting, of course, that doing it that way, you would need to "forward" all of the various control properties that you want to be able to set, from the `UserControl` object to the `ItemsPanel`. Some, like `Background`, you can probably just set on the `UserControl` and have the desired effect, but others are specifically applicable to the `ItemsControl`, like `ItemTemplate`, `ItemTemplateSelector`, etc. You'll have to figure out which those are, and bind the properties, with the source being the `UserControl` and the target the `ItemsControl` inside, declaring as dependency properties in your `UserControl` class any that aren't already part of the `UserControl` type.

Here's a little sample program that shows how the above could be used:

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestSO43008469HeaderFooterWrapPanel.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO43008469HeaderFooterWrapPanel"
        xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
      <TextBlock Text="Header: "/>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding Header, ElementName=headerFooterWrapPanel1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
      <TextBlock Text="Footer: "/>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding Footer, ElementName=headerFooterWrapPanel1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Random List Change" Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <l:HeaderFooterWrapPanel x:Name="headerFooterWrapPanel1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                             Header="Header Item" Footer="Footer Item" Grid.Row="3">
      <l:HeaderFooterWrapPanel.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type s:String}">
          <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="16"/>
          </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
      </l:HeaderFooterWrapPanel.Resources>
    </l:HeaderFooterWrapPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

For the purpose of illustration, I've set the `Window.DataContext` property to the `Window` object itself. This isn't normally a good idea — it's better to have a proper view model to use as the data context — but for a simple program like this, it's fine. Similarly, the `Header` and `Footer` properties would normally be bound to some view model property instead of just tying one framework element's property to another.

**C#:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Items.Add("Item #1");
        Items.Add("Item #2");
        Items.Add("Item #3");
    }

    private static readonly Random _random = new Random();

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (Items.Count > 0 ? _random.Next(2) : 0)
        {
            case 0: // add
                Items.Insert(_random.Next(Items.Count + 1), $"Item #{_random.Next()}");
                break;
            case 1: // remove
                Items.RemoveAt(_random.Next(Items.Count));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I was making this much more complicated than it needed to be.Thanks for such a complete and informative answer! I did notice a small bug in your provided code for the _OnHeaderFooterPropertyChanged() method though - you're always setting the object to be the header! My revised code for that method passes in the DependencyObjectPropertyChangedEventArgs to the method and sets the content to the NewValue property of that argument: `panel._composedCollection[index] = e.NewValue;`

Comment: @aswanson: yes, good catch. The incorrect code was a victim of incomplete refactoring. :) Your fix is a good one; I've edited the code example to match.